# Comparing two CSV files in linux

Tags: linux, csv, awk

I have two CSV files with me in the following format:

File1:

```
No.1, No.2
983264,72342349
763498,81243970
736493,83740940
```

File2:

```
No.1,No.2
"7938493","7364987"
"2153187","7387910"
"736493","83740940"
```

I need to compare the two files and output the matched,unmatched values. 
I did it through awk:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk 'BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ","
}
if (FNR==1){next}
NR>1 && NR==FNR {
    a[$1];
    next
}
FNR>1 {
    print ($1 in a) ? $1 FS "Match" : $1 FS "In file2 but not in file1"
    delete a[$1]
}
END {
    for (x in a) {
        print x FS "In file1 but not in file2"
    }
}'file1 file2
```

But the output is:

```
"7938493",In file2 but not in file1
"2153187",In file2 but not in file1
"8172470",In file2 but not in file1
7938493,In file1 but not in file2
2153187,In file1 but not in file2
8172470,In file1 but not in file2
```

Can you please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: This can't be your actual script as you have a syntax error: `a[$1};`. What is your desired output for the input you have posted?

Comment: That just happened by mistake. 
My desired output is to print the common values with the comment as in the script and the values which are in file1 but not in file2 and vice-versa with their respective comments. But the values are getting printed in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some corrections to your script:

```
BEGIN {
    # FS = OFS = ","
    FS = "[,\"]+"
    OFS = ", "
}
# if (FNR==1){next}
FNR == 1 {next}

# NR>1 && NR==FNR {
NR==FNR {
    a[$1];
    next
}
# FNR>1 {
$2 in a {
    # print ($1 in a) ? $1 FS "Match" : $1 FS "In file2 but not in file1"
    print ($2 in a) ? $2 OFS "Match" : $2 "In file2 but not in file1"
    delete a[$2]
}
END {
    for (x in a) {
        print x, "In file1 but not in file2"
    }
}
```

This is an awk script, so you can run it like `awk -f script.awk file1 file2`. Doing so gives these results:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file1 file2
736493, Match
763498, In file1 but not in file2
983264, In file1 but not in file2
```

The main problem with your script was that it didn't correctly handle the double quotes around the numbers in `file2`. I changed the input field separator so that the double quotes are treated as part of the separator to deal with this. As a result, the first field `$1` in the second file is empty (it is the bit between the start of the line and the first `"`), so you need to use `$2` to refer to the first value you're interested in. Aside from that, I removed some redundant conditions from your other blocks and used `OFS` rather than `FS` in your first `print` statement.

Comment: @UDITA I'm glad to hear that. Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if your problem is solved, by clicking on the tick mark next to it.